# PN Junction paradox or something else?

Tags: transistors, diodes, semiconductors, physics, circuits

[![I am having problem understanding reversed biased pn junction as the explaination provided by my book or any other source about flow of current in forward biased condition seems equally applicable for RB conditions also i.e. current should flow in both conditions.

Read the explaination of my book it say,in FB electrons and holes combine near the pn junction and cease to exist and at the same time a covalent bond breaks near the positive terminal of battery in p region,of which electron travel to the positive terminal of battery and hole towards the junction and at the same time an electron releases from negetive terminal of battery and into the n region hence completing the circuit.

Now what I am saying,apply the same rules in RB and current will flow regardless of biasing.As in RB postive terminal is connected to N-type and negetive to P-type and holes in p-region and electrons in n-region are pulled away from the junction.Now what should happen is electron from negetive terminal of battery should combine with holes in the p-type and a covalent bond break at pn junction,of which electron should travel to the n-region and electron present in n-region should move to positive terminal of battery and hence completing the circuit.So where is the catch. ][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRgY8.jpg[image]

Comment: I'm kind of missing the difference to your last question? Same problem: PN junction, charge carrier depletion in RB.

Comment: You seem to be forgetting (although being repeatedly pointed at!) that the same field that leads to carrier depletion is what makes your  "battery send electrons". Nothing here is paradoxical; you're just trying to ignore the physics ;)

Comment: @Marcus Müller Good to see you again sir I took your advice and edited the question.And yes that post didn't resolve my confusion that's why I posted another question.And yes this is what I am asking why the field just not suck the electron from n-region and pour into the p-region as the field is trying send electron from negetive to positive terminal of battery

Comment: It simply can't; there's nothing to suck. Same reason why there isn't a standing spark between the terminals of your battery. Air is an insulator. And so is charge-carrier-depleted semiconductor.

Comment: @Marcus Müller Yeah you are absolutely right as pointed by many other I get that,that it's insulated and here insulation means completely filled valance band i.e. no electron in conduction band but why doesn't the covalent bond gets break in the depletion region and a hole and electron move in opposite direction creating a current,as when my book explains FB condition it says covalent breaks in p-region near positive terminal of battery why doesn't the same thing happens here.Is my book wrong?Please read the passage I provided in the picture.

Comment: Why doesn't a kitten spontaneously form when you put a diode in RB? The very defnition of covalence band is that the energy isn't sufficient to do that.

Comment: @Marcus Müller Then how does covalent bond gets break in FB condition.And what's kitten?

Comment: you're confusing things; nothing breaks, there's no bonds involved here whatsoever (this isn't chemistry with molecules; this is a semiconductor crystal lattice). Also, you need to to look at the band diagram again. The bands shift. (A kitten is a young cat. I just used that as an example that I could just as well claim that should happen, but is extremely unrealistic.).

Comment: @Marcus Müller Why are you seeing things differently no matter from which perspective I look at it result must agree.If there nothing breaks how would you explain current in FB condition specially how an electron gets to positive terminal of battery if there is no breaking of covalent bond.

Comment: you've got something in the basics wrong. There's no covalent bonds that get broken here, anyway, in any diode. The covalence band *shifts*; that's not the same as bonds getting broken. Just because these are electrons from the same hull as involved in covalence bonds doesn't mean that this model of molecules interacting has anything to do with semiconductor physics. Band diagrams: re-study them. You've got a misconception there, or rather, multiple.

Comment: @Marcus Müller What do you mean by covalence band do you mean the valance band?

Comment: err yes, sorry got confused when you brought up the unrelated concept of covalence bonds.

Comment: Marcus Müller So you are saying there is shifting of bond not the breaking right.If that's the case then how does the electrons entering the extrinsic semiconductor leaves it.As to leave the semiconductor they should be in conduction band.

Comment: there's no bonds here. You mean bands, right?

Comment: @Marcus Müller No I meant the bonds regardless.So what you exactly mean by t"the valance band shifts" do you mean energy between valance band and conduction band band gets lower?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work as you say, with holes and electrons moving away from the junction.  But only for a short moment.  Then it stops.  It stops because the holes in the p-type side moved away from the junction, and the electrons in the n-type side also moved away from the junction.  This creates a wide insulating layer, located at the junction.   (The word "insulating" actually means "lacks mobile charges.")

In other words, during reverse-bias of any diode, the voltage of the power supply is sweeping out the charge-carriers from the junction.  The "depletion layer" widens.

But, because any *doped* semiconductor material is always full of immobile charged atoms (the original dopant ions,) this means that the semiconductor depletion-layer has pos&neg "plates," and it behaves as a static-charged capacitor.  The n-type will be strongly positive-charged whenever its electrons are swept out.  The p-type side is opposite, and the two together form an insulating dielectric with a built-in voltage.   The wider the depletion-layer, the higher the voltage across the "capacitor plates."

If we apply 30V reverse bias, then the holes and electrons are pulled away, and the depletion layer widens.   But it only becomes exactly wide enough, until the "newly-exposed" ions in the insulating semiconductor have 30V on their "charged capacitor" plates.  This voltage exactly opposes the applied RB reverse-biase voltage from an external power supply.

Doped semiconductors are "electrets," they are insulating materials with strong charges locked into their matrix.   But also, semiconductors are filled with an equal amount of opposite, movable charges.  These opposite charges cause the semiconductor to become neutral-charged, and also conductive.   However, if we can sweep the charges out of the semiconductor, then it becomes a charged insulator, an "electret."

(An "electret" is the electrostatic analogy to the permanent magnet.  Rather than being a permanent-magnetized ferromagnet, an "electret" is a permanent-charged dielectric.)

ADDED:

During reverse bias, immense numbers of hole/electron pairs AREN'T created in the depletion layer.  Yes, during forward-bias the hole/electron pairs are canceled out as they fall together, emitting IR photons as they do.   But the opposite doesn't happen (no thermodynamic backwardds-time events, where photons magically come in for no reason, to break covalent bonds and thus create any large population of hole-electron pairs in the depletion layer.)

---

HOWEVER, this hole/electron "pair production" process DOES occur elsewhere in the diode.  It occurs at the spot where the external metal terminal touches the p-doped side of the diode.

If we touch a metal terminal against p-type silicon, we should be creating anothee diode in series with the man pn junction (creating a Schottky rectifier, a metal/semiconductor junction.)  This produces an unwanted pn junction, since this new junction faces backwards when compared to the main pn junction (and therefore, the diode as a whole would always be turned off!  Opposite junctions connected in series will block diode current.)

To eliminate this unwanted effect, we must form a nonrectifying contact, a metal/semiconductor bond that acts more like a copper-iron thermocouple than like a Schottky diode.  Look up "nonrectifying contact" or "nonrectifying junctions" chapter in semiconductor theory-textbooks.

To intentionally produce non-rectifying contacts, first we heavily dope the semiconductor (called ++p doping, or --n doping.)  Because of some mysterious[note1] quantum-mechanical effects, the heavy doping causes the semiconductor to act like a metal, with a dense charge-cloud inside, and only insignificant depletion layers will be formed by contact with other materials.  (In other words, iron and copper in contact will not form insulating depletion zones, and don't act like diodes.  Same with metal against p++ or n-- doped layers.)

So, first apply ++p doping to the p-type end of your diode, then attach the metal wire there.  When the main pn diode junction is forward-biased, this non-rectifying contact is reverse biased, and new holes are being created at the metal/semiconductor contact.  Covalent bonds of the semiconductor are spontaneously breaking via QM tunneling or thermal vibrations, and a cloud of holes flies off into the ++p type semiconductor, and an equal cloud of electrons flies off into the metal wire.  (Side effect: the temperature of this junction starts dropping.)

(Another classic nonrectifying junction is found in "TE modules" or "Peltier coolers," where numerous ++p-type and --n-type semiconductor blocks are attached to thin copper connecting straps, yet none of these junctions create any diodes.  They only create thermocouples, where the built-in contact-potential is much larger than is expected for metal-metal thermocouples.)

[1] Not entirely mysterious: any depletion zones formed by metal-against-++p semiconductor will be incredibly thin:  thinner than the wavelength of electron matter-waves.  When electron particles behave as waves, they cannot "see" the insignificant thinness of electrostatic energy-barriers in depletion-zones produced by metal-metal contacts.  Or in other words, if a depletion zone is too thin, electrons will tunnel freely across, even if the depletion zone offers a high energy-barrier, and where Classical Mechanics would predict that it should be an insulator.  The same is true both for metal-against-(++p), and metal-against-(--n) semiconductor contacts.   Then, when this too-thin depletion zone is reverse-biased by an external power supply, the "wave-like" covalent-bond electrons "tunnel out" of the ++p semiconductor (also they absorb thermal vibrations as they jump to the higher energy-band of the metal wire, so the metal-to-(++p) contact becomes colder.  It's just the Peltier Effect of thermocouple junctions.)  What's the size of the small voltage on this junction?  DOESN'T MATTER, because it's exactly opposed by the equal-opposite small voltage appearing at the other metal contact of the diode (as well as opposed by the tiny voltage appearing at the places where +p touches ++p, etc.)  As a whole, it behaves like a copper-iron-copper thermocouple, which creates zero net voltage on its terminals, because the two identical thermocouples in series are wired in opposite directions.

Comment: What you are saying is an insulating layer is preventing the conduction of current i.e. that is full valence band.But as my books explain the flow of current in FB condition it says a covalent bond breaks in p-region when a electron and hole combines at junction during conduction.So why doesn't same happen with the insulating layer,the complete covalent bond should break of which electron should travel to n-region and a hole to p-region,what is the problem.Is my book wrong?

Comment: @AzazelDemonEmperor during electron/hole recombination they emit IR light (or emit large lattice-vibrations.)   The reverse doesn't occur, unless we blast the junction with light, or heat it 100s of degrees.   In other words, the recombination is not thermodynamically reversible, because photons don't magically come in backwards to strike the junction during reverse bias.   ( The real question is, during forward bias, at the place where wire touches the ++p type layer far from the junction, WHY are holes created there?  Remember that ++p doped silicon is "metallic," not "semiconduct." )

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I am asking why are holes created near where the wire touches p-region and don't in depletion region.And what do you mean by "++p doped silicon is metallic not semiconductor" do you mean p-type is metallic?

Comment: @AzazelDemonEmperor the secret is "metallic-mode" high doping of silicon: find chapters on ++p doping and --n doping.  See my answer above, I've added more.

Comment: Now this answers my question,why covalent bonds do not break at pn junction in RB condition whereas they break in p-region near positive terminal of battery in FB condition.I did read about non rectifying and rectifying contact,the article refered to them as ohmic and non ohmic contacts and it said a contact to be ohmic or non- ohmic depends upon the schotkey barrier and it can be "naively predicted by schotkey-mott rule".Thanks!! For the answer I really understand now how the diode works.

Answer (score 0):

In reverse bias, the high voltage attracts carriers away from the doped region, creating a large region devoid of free carriers. The flow of electrons/holes stops.

Comment: I am saying if their are holes in p region why doesnt electron coming from n-region just combine with the holes.And the same amount of electron and hole could generate by breaking covalent bonds

Comment: Because as analogsystemsrf says the voltage prevents that. The electron or the hole would have to go against the electric field. (Just like a stone does not fall 'upwards' against the gravity field)

Comment: @Oldfart How voltage is preventing that,as battery clearly wants to send an electron from its negetive terminal to positive terminal how electron is going against the electric field

Comment: *"battery clearly wants to send an electron"* that is not how it works. The battery generates an electric field.The electrons are attracted/moved by that field. When reverse biased  the electron and holes the PN region are attracted 'away' from the junction thus you get a non-conduction area.

Comment: @oldfart Yeah i know battery generates electric field but that doesn't changes the question.Becouse electric field clearly wants to send an electron from negetive terminal of battery to positive terminal.I am saying why doesn't the electron coming from the negetive terminal of battery just pour into the p-region and electron in n-region attracts towards positive terminal of battery as the "electric field" is pushing the electron from negetive terminal of battery to p-region to n-region and to positive terminal of battery and pulling at the same time.

Comment: @AzazelDemonEmperor I believe you are struggling with the concept of dynamical equilibrium and the transient required to reach it. So, yes, there is an appreciable movement of charge in reverse bias, but that is only the transient required to reach the new equilibrium with a wider depletion zone. Once there, charge will only trickle at a very low level. And you need to understand that the holes in the p region are already formed, the bonds were broken when you doped the material and the energy you need to 'make em move' is not the bandgap, they are basically free once they are formed.

Comment: @Sredni Vashtar Good to see you.If the holes are formed olny when we doped so there must be limited no of holes,so how does new holes form when a electron combines with holes.For example if there are 'n' number of electron and p number of holes(for simplicity considering p=n) if a hole combines with a electron there are n-1 electron and p-1 holes so how number of holes and electron remains sufficient in FB condition.

Comment: @AzazelDemonEmperor you need to find one of those band diagrams where electrons are shown as black balls and holes as white bubble. Imagine the intrinsic semiconductor with all black balls in the valence band and nothing in conduction band. Now dope it with acceptor atoms: these will place empty 'traps' near the valence band, and electrons there will jump up with just a nudge by thermal energy. The black balls leaving the valence band will leave behind white bubbles. Now look what you have: bubbles free to move in the valence band: you need almost no energy - they are almost at the same level

Comment: There are different 'bubble-ball' interactions with different energy required to take place.  1. Bubble moves in the valence band, i.e. electrons move in the emptyspaces that are bubbles. This requires almost no energy  - 2. Ball goes from valence band to trap. This require a bit of energy, but it's just a fraction of eV and thermal energy will do that for you   - 3. Ball in the conduction band fall into the valence band in the empty space represented by a bubble. This releases a good amount of energy, at least as big as the bandgap - you might end up with IR radiation, or even visible light.

Comment: 3' you can also have a ball in the valence band jumping up in the conduction band, becoming a free ball up there. As with the recombination process, the energy involved is at least the bandgap, and in this case you need to supply it. In intrinsic semiconductors at ambient temperature only a negligible portion of electrons have this energy, but you can increase their number by turning up the temperature. Semiconductor reduce their resistivity with increasing temperature, contrary to what happens with conductors.

Comment: Keep 1,2,3 separated in your mind and always ask yourself if you have the energy to make'em happen. (truth be told, energy is just one thing you need, but that's another story).

Comment: @Sredni Vashtar I get your explaintion that electron of n-region fall into valance band in p-region where they occupy the vacant space and from there they move from one vacancy to other or as you pointed out "Ball moves from one bubble to another".But if continue the journey of this electron,that fell from n-region conduction band to p-region valance band,it is moving from one vacancy to other towards negetive terminal of battery and just here at the end i.e. where wire joins to the p-region how should this electron will leave through the wire?

Comment: @AzazelDemonEmperor I did not mention the n-region. The examples I made were based on a p-doped material. This is why in the other question I suggested you study how conduction happens in a slab of n-type only material, then in a slab of p-type material. Pay attention to which carriers are responsible of the current. It seems to me you are mixing electrons up and you seem to think that the hole 'movement' in the valence band can only happen when electrons jump to/from the conduction band. It is not the case.

Comment: @Sredni Vashtar No,I know that electron don't need jump to and from conduction band.Once in valance band they can move forward by occupying one vacancy to other ,but what I am saying is what happens when these electron reach at the junction of wire and semiconductor,how do they continue their motion from here?

Comment: @AzazelDemonEmperor I see wbeaty gave already you the answer you were looking for. For further reading, I refer you to chapter 16 of McKelvey's 1966 book, "Solid State and Semiconductor Physics". It has the simplest explanation of metal-metal and metal-semiconductor interfaces I've found.

Comment: @Sredni Vashtar Thank you for the suggestion.I read the book and it cleared a lot of things.